# iPhone 8, iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone X device code

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-x

I'm using the below code to get the device name

```
NSString* code = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Which gives the result as follows and mapped to devices

> @"iPhone9,1" :@"iPhone 7",
>   @"iPhone9,3" :@"iPhone 7",
>   @"iPhone9,2" :@"iPhone 7 Plus",
>   @"iPhone9,4" :@"iPhone 7 Plus",

Do we have the new device code for the new devices that are released (iPhone 8, iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone X)

Comment: This info probably won't be available until those devices are released. Then again, there seem to be plenty of leaks...

Comment: I'd like to know what you need this information for. What phone the user has is rarely what you need to base your decisions on.

Comment: @gnasher729  I use this information for analytics purpose to see which devices are used to access my application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit: This has been corrected. The iPhone X is **NOT** iPhone10,5 and iPhone10,6.

- **iPhone 8:** `iPhone10,1` & `iPhone10,4`
- **iPhone 8 Plus:** `iPhone10,2` & `iPhone10,5`
- **iPhone X:** `iPhone10,3` & `iPhone10,6`

Answer (score 5):

### Note: Update for 2020 iPhone Models in Obj-C code

### Swift 4.1+

NOTE: See Obj-C code for the newest device additions.

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

class DeviceInfo {
    static func platform() -> String? {
        var systemInfo = utsname()
        uname(&systemInfo)
        let modelCode = withUnsafePointer(to: &systemInfo.machine) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: CChar.self, capacity: 1) {
                ptr in String.init(validatingUTF8: ptr)
            }
        }
        return modelCode
    }

    static func deviceType() -> String {
        if let platform = platform(), let device = deviceDict[platform] {
            return device
        }
        return "unknown"
    }

    static let deviceDict: Dictionary<String, String> = [
        "iPhone1,1" : "iPhone (1st generation)",
        "iPhone1,2" : "iPhone 3G",
        "iPhone2,1" : "iPhone 3GS",
        "iPhone3,1" : "iPhone 4 (GSM)",
        "iPhone3,2" : "iPhone 4 (GSM, 2nd revision)",
        "iPhone3,3" : "iPhone 4 (Verizon)",
        "iPhone4,1" : "iPhone 4S",
        "iPhone5,1" : "iPhone 5 (GSM)",
        "iPhone5,2" : "iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone5,3" : "iPhone 5c (GSM)",
        "iPhone5,4" : "iPhone 5c (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone6,1" : "iPhone 5s (GSM)",
        "iPhone6,2" : "iPhone 5s (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone7,2" : "iPhone 6",
        "iPhone7,1" : "iPhone 6 Plus",
        "iPhone8,1" : "iPhone 6s",
        "iPhone8,2" : "iPhone 6s Plus",
        "iPhone8,4" : "iPhone SE",
        "iPhone9,1" : "iPhone 7 (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone9,3" : "iPhone 7 (GSM)",
        "iPhone9,2" : "iPhone 7 Plus (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone9,4" : "iPhone 7 Plus (GSM)",
        "iPhone10,1" : "iPhone 8 (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone10,4" : "iPhone 8 (GSM)",
        "iPhone10,2" : "iPhone 8 Plus (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone10,5" : "iPhone 8 Plus (GSM)",
        "iPhone10,3" : "iPhone X (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone10,6" : "iPhone X (GSM)",
        "iPhone11,1" : "iPhone XR (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone11,2" : "iPhone XS (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone11,3" : "iPhone XS (GSM)",
        "iPhone11,4" : "iPhone XS Max (GSM+CDMA)",
        "iPhone11,5" : "iPhone XS Max (GSM, Dual Sim, China)",
        "iPhone11,6" : "iPhone XS Max (GSM)",
        "iPhone11,8" : "iPhone XR (GSM)",
        "iPod1,1" : "iPod Touch 1G",
        "iPod2,1" : "iPod Touch 2G",
        "iPod3,1" : "iPod Touch 3G",
        "iPod4,1" : "iPod Touch 4G",
        "iPod5,1" : "iPod Touch 5G",
        "iPod7,1" : "iPod Touch 6G",
        "iPad1,1" : "iPad",
        "iPad2,1" : "iPad 2 (WiFi)",
        "iPad2,2" : "iPad 2 (GSM)",
        "iPad2,3" : "iPad 2 (CDMA)",
        "iPad2,4" : "iPad 2 (WiFi)",
        "iPad2,5" : "iPad Mini (WiFi)",
        "iPad2,6" : "iPad Mini (GSM)",
        "iPad2,7" : "iPad Mini (CDMA)",
        "iPad3,1" : "iPad 3 (WiFi)",
        "iPad3,2" : "iPad 3 (CDMA)",
        "iPad3,3" : "iPad 3 (GSM)",
        "iPad3,4" : "iPad 4 (WiFi)",
        "iPad3,5" : "iPad 4 (GSM)",
        "iPad3,6" : "iPad 4 (CDMA)",
        "iPad4,1" : "iPad Air (WiFi)",
        "iPad4,2" : "iPad Air (GSM)",
        "iPad4,3" : "iPad Air (CDMA)",
        "iPad4,4" : "iPad Mini 2 (WiFi)",
        "iPad4,5" : "iPad Mini 2 (Cellular)",
        "iPad4,6" : "iPad Mini 2 (Cellular)",
        "iPad4,7" : "iPad Mini 3 (WiFi)",
        "iPad4,8" : "iPad Mini 3 (Cellular)",
        "iPad4,9" : "iPad Mini 3 (Cellular)",
        "iPad5,1" : "iPad Mini 4 (WiFi)",
        "iPad5,2" : "iPad Mini 4 (Cellular)",
        "iPad5,3" : "iPad Air 2 (WiFi)",
        "iPad5,4" : "iPad Air 2 (Cellular)",
        "iPad6,3" : "iPad Pro 9.7-inch (WiFi)",
        "iPad6,4" : "iPad Pro 9.7-inch (Cellular)",
        "iPad6,7" : "iPad Pro 12.9-inch (WiFi)",
        "iPad6,8" : "iPad Pro 12.9-inch (Cellular)",
        "iPad6,11" : "iPad 5 (WiFi)",
        "iPad6,12" : "iPad 5 (Cellular)",
        "iPad7,1" : "iPad Pro 12.9-inch 2 (WiFi)",
        "iPad7,2" : "iPad Pro 12.9-inch 2 (Cellular)",
        "iPad7,3" : "iPad Pro 10.5-inch (WiFi)",
        "iPad7,4" : "iPad Pro 10.5-inch (Cellular)",
        "iPad7,5" : "iPad 6 (WiFi)",
        "iPad7,6" : "iPad 6 (Cellular)",
        "iPad8,1" : "iPad Pro 11-inch (WiFi)",
        "iPad8,2" : "iPad Pro 11-inch (WiFi, 1TB)",
        "iPad8,3" : "iPad Pro 11-inch (Cellular)",
        "iPad8,4" : "iPad Pro 11-inch (Cellular, 1TB)",
        "iPad8,5" : "iPad Pro 12.9-inch 3 (WiFi)",
        "iPad8,6" : "iPad Pro 12.9-inch 3 (WiFi, 1TB)",
        "iPad8,7" : "iPad Pro 12.9-inch 3 (Cellular)",
        "iPad8,8" : "iPad Pro 12.9-inch 3 (Cellular, 1TB)",
        "i386" : "Simulator",
        "x86_64" : "Simulator",
        ]
}
```

I will update the answer when I have the new watches platform strings.

### Obj-C

```
 + (NSString *)platformString{
        NSString *platform = [Settings platform];

        //iPhone
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone (1st generation)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4 (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"])    return @"iPhone 4 (GSM, 2nd revision)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"iPhone 4 (Verizon)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])    return @"iPhone 5c (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])    return @"iPhone 5s (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    return @"iPhone 6";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    return @"iPhone 6 Plus";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,1"])    return @"iPhone 6s";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,2"])    return @"iPhone 6s Plus";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,4"])    return @"iPhone SE";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone9,1"])    return @"iPhone 7 (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone9,3"])    return @"iPhone 7 (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone9,2"])    return @"iPhone 7 Plus (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone9,4"])    return @"iPhone 7 Plus (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone10,1"])    return @"iPhone 8 (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone10,4"])    return @"iPhone 8 (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone10,2"])    return @"iPhone 8 Plus (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone10,5"])    return @"iPhone 8 Plus (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone10,3"])    return @"iPhone X (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone10,6"])    return @"iPhone X (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone11,1"])    return @"iPhone XR (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone11,2"])    return @"iPhone XS (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone11,3"])    return @"iPhone XS (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone11,4"])    return @"iPhone XS Max (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone11,5"])    return @"iPhone XS Max (GSM, Dual Sim, China)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone11,6"])    return @"iPhone XS Max (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone11,8"])    return @"iPhone XR (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone12,1"])    return @"iPhone 11";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone12,2"])    return @"iPhone 11 Pro";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone12,3"])    return @"iPhone 11 Pro Max";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone12,5"])    return @"iPhone 11 Pro Max";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone12,8"])    return @"iPhone SE 2nd Gen.";

//iPod Touch
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 5G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod7,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 6G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod9,1"])      return @"iPod Touch (7G)";

//iPad
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad (1st generation)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2 (Wi-Fi, Mid 2012)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad (3rd generation) (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad (3rd generation) (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad (3rd generation) (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad (4th generation) (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad (4th generation) (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad (4th generation) (GSM+CDMA)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad Air (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad Air (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,3"])      return @"iPad Air (China)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])      return @"iPad Mini 2 (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])      return @"iPad Mini 2 (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,6"])      return @"iPad Mini 2 (China)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,7"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,8"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,9"])      return @"iPad Mini 3 (China)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,1"])      return @"iPad Mini 4 (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,2"])      return @"iPad Mini 4 (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"])      return @"iPad Air 2 (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad6,3"])      return @"iPad Pro 9.7\" (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad6,4"])      return @"iPad Pro 9.7\" (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad6,7"])      return @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad6,8"])      return @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad6,11"])     return @"iPad (5th generation) (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad6,12"])     return @"iPad (5th generation) (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad7,1"])      return @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (2nd generation) (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad7,2"])      return @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (2nd generation) (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad7,3"])      return @"iPad Pro 10.5\" (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad7,4"])      return @"iPad Pro 10.5\" (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad7,5"])      return @"iPad 6 (WiFi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad7,6"])      return @"iPad 6 (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad8,1"])      return @"iPad Pro 11\" (2018) (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad8,2"])      return @"iPad Pro 11\" (2018) (Wi-Fi, 1TB)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad8,3"])      return @"iPad Pro 11\" (2018) (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad8,4"])      return @"iPad Pro 11\" (2018) (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad8,5"])      return @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (2018) (3rd generation) (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad8,6"])      return @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (2018) (3rd generation) (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad8,7"])      return @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (2018) (3rd generation) (Wi-Fi, 1TB)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad8,8"])      return @"iPad Pro 12.9\" (2018) (3rd generation) (Cellular, 1TB)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad11,1"])     return @"iPad mini (2019) (5th generation) (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad11,2"])     return @"iPad mini (2019) (5th generation) (Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad11,3"])     return @"iPad Air (2019) (3rd generation) (Wi-Fi)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad11,4"])     return @"iPad Air (2019) (3rd generation) (Cellular)";

//Apple TV
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"AppleTV2,1"])   return @"Apple TV 2G";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"AppleTV3,1"])   return @"Apple TV 3";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"AppleTV3,2"])   return @"Apple TV 3 (2013)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"AppleTV5,3"])   return @"Apple TV 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"AppleTV6,2"])   return @"Apple TV 4K";

//Apple Watch
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch1,1"])     return @"Apple Watch (1st generation) (38mm)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch1,2"])     return @"Apple Watch (1st generation) (42mm)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch2,6"])     return @"Apple Watch Series 1 (38mm)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch2,7"])     return @"Apple Watch Series 1 (42mm)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch2,3"])     return @"Apple Watch Series 2 (38mm)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch2,4"])     return @"Apple Watch Series 2 (42mm)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch3,1"])     return @"Apple Watch Series 3 (38mm Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch3,2"])     return @"Apple Watch Series 3 (42mm Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch3,3"])     return @"Apple Watch Series 3 (38mm)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch3,4"])     return @"Apple Watch Series 3 (42mm)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch4,1"])     return @"Apple Watch Series 4 (40mm)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch4,2"])     return @"Apple Watch Series 4 (44mm)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch4,3"])     return @"Apple Watch Series 4 (40mm Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch4,4"])     return @"Apple Watch Series 4 (44mm Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch5,1"])     return @"Apple Watch Series 5 (40mm)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch5,2"])     return @"Apple Watch Series 5 (44mm)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch5,3"])     return @"Apple Watch Series 5 (40mm Cellular)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"Watch5,4"])     return @"Apple Watch Series 5 (44mm Cellular)";

//Simulator
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";

        return platform;
        return [@"Unknown : " stringByAppendingString:platform];
    }
```

This is the actual code to get the devices platform.

Note the `class methods` and the code is inside an `NSObject Class` called `Settings`.

You may easily change it to an `instance method` with the first line `- (NSString *)platform {` and `- (NSString *)platformString {`, also call the platform: `NSString *platform = [self platform];` at the top of the `platformString` code.

```
+ (NSString *) platform{
    int mib[2];
    size_t len;
    char *machine;

    mib[0] = CTL_HW;
    mib[1] = HW_MACHINE;

    sysctl(mib, 2u, NULL, &len, NULL, 0);
    machine = malloc(len);
    sysctl(mib, 2u, machine, &len, NULL, 0);

    NSString *platform = @(machine);
    free(machine);
    return platform;
}
```

Comment: It'd be a lot cleaner to store the data in a dictionary and get the value given a `platform` string. I'm pretty sure it would also be faster, since dictionaries perform hash lookups.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Your right it might be faster with dictionary, but it will take time to build the dictionary and this is only one call that is performed, thus this is faster.

Comment: @HannesSverrisson OK, but I don't mean that iclarified.com data is reliable, I just wanted to point out the difference. The only reliable source I know is https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models and it doesn't list the "iPhone11,1".