# What are the model names for IPhone 8 and iPhone X?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11

Can anyone who have access to iPhone 8 and iPhone X let me know the model names? It could be accessed by `UIDevice.current.modelName`.

Comment: `iPhone 8 : iPhone10,1 ou iPhone10,3 iPhone 8 Plus : iPhone10,2 ou iPhone10,4 iPhone X : iPhone10,5 ou iPhone10,6`

get information from here - https://iphonesoft.fr/2016/10/31/liste-codes-identifiants-iphone-ipod-ipad-watch`

Comment: Look at my answer i have posted code for Swift + Objective-C https://stackoverflow.com/a/46291942/970957

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information as @Anbu mentioned are:

- iPhone 8: iPhone10,1 and iPhone10,4
- iPhone 8 Plus: iPhone10,2 and iPhone10,5
- iPhone X: iPhone10,3 and iPhone10,6

Remember if you want to use `UIDevice.current.modelName` you need to create your own extension since this is not a default value in `UIDevice.current`.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. My iPhone 8 is reported as iPhone10,4. I also see several iPhone 10,4 and iPhone 10,5 using our app. So I guess 10,4 is iPhone 8 and 10,5 iPhone 8 Plus. I also see one iPhone 10,3 running iOS 11.0.1.

Comment: indeed, the info is not accurate. https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models

Comment: Fixed. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46231608